# Why is the PSCyr font package is not on CTAN?

Tags: fonts, cyrillic

There is old and famous cyrillic font package named PSCyr which is mentioned in nearly every russian guide about setting up LaTeX for writing documents with cyrillic  letters.

Actually I want to ask two questions regarding this package:

1. Why is it still not on CTAN and not available in major LaTeX distros?
2. Is there any more useful (and widely used) and modern alternatives?

Comment: There is some license issues with PSCyr and TeX Live mentioned in this mailing list, but nothing about license issues with CTAN.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Material gets added to CTAN because people submit it to them. Thus there is no guarantee that any given TeX package or font will be on CTAN: it is down to the author(s) of the material to send it. The CTAN team do ask people for submissions from time to time, but it seems that they have limited success. There are some people who seem not to want to submit to the central repository, preferring that users get material directly from them (as was much more common pre-CTAN). CTAN takes material is any license, I guess with the only proviso being that they need permission to redistribute.

Focussing on the current case, [David's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/128188) shows that some parts of PSCyr are on CTAN as part of their BaKoMa holding, but that does not seem to include the standard files for addition to a  general TeX system (BaKoMa is a shareware TeX system): the files look to be BaKoMa-specific. To get it on to CTAN, I guess you'll need to contact the author (web site is I think http://www.tex.uniyar.ac.ru/, but is all in Russian so I can't be sure!).

Comment: Here's a link: ftp://scon155.phys.msu.su/pub/russian/psfonts

Answer (score 4):

Homepage for PSCyr 0.4 is [here](ftp://scon155.phys.msu.su/pub/russian/psfonts/).

I found a useful [bash script](https://gist.github.com/beresovskiy/8654052/) to facilitate installation of latest PSCyr for texlive (included with pscyr install.sh script is for tetex). Worked fine for me under Ubuntu Trusty.

Hope that helps

Comment: Do you know why the package's license isn't aligned with one of the licenses that are known to be acceptable for distribution via CTAN and TeXlive? (I'm thinking of licenses such as lppl, gnu, and MIT, to name but a few.)

Comment: No, I don't. Try asking the author